# Symfony2 on IIS setup

Tags: php, symfony, iis

I installed Symfony2 on Windows 8.1. The files are stored under IIS in wwwroot. 
Everything runs very well when I use the internal built-in PHP server. I can access the site through localhost:8000/app_dev.php. 

When I try to access the site straight through localhost (localhost/test_project/web/app.php), I can get to the site, but it doesn't update with my changes even after I close the browser and completely reload the site. I have the same problem on the internal PHP server when I try localhost:8000/app.php - my changes aren't there.

Questions: 
1. Why are my app and app_dev showing different content? 
2. How can I set up Symfony to run on IIS and not need the internal server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because app.php uses cached files and you need to clear framework cache to see your changes. It is production version of your web.

   `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`
2. localhost/test_project/web/**app_dev.php**

Please look at [official Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/configuration.html#environments) for explanation.